# Cursor moves to the last character every time I try to edit the text from middle in vue-tel-input package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, cursor, vue-tel-input

I am using the [vue-tel-input](https://github.com/iamstevendao/vue-tel-input) library in the Vue 3 project, and I noticed that whenever I try to edit the phone number, the cursor always moves to the last character, making it difficult to edit the text.

Steps to see the problem-

1. Go to the [demo](https://vue-tel-input.iamstevendao.com/).
2. Type any phone number inside the text box.
3. Click on, the "Show Options" link.
4. Uncheck the "autoFormat" checkbox.
5. Now, try to edit the phone number from the middle, you should see the cursor jumping to the last character position.

**Note**- This problem does not occur in the Firefox browser.

Here is the sample code-

```
<template>
  <vue-tel-input v-model="phone" mode="international"></vue-tel-input>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { VueTelInput } from 'vue-tel-input';
  import 'vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css';

  export default {
    components: {
      VueTelInput,
    },

    setup() {
      const phone = ref(null);

      return {
        value,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

I have tried the below solution-

```
// Get the current cursor position
const input = this.$refs.phoneRef.$refs.input;
const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart;

// Update the phone number


// Set the cursor position back to where it was
this.$nextTick(() => {
  input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
});
```

One more I have tried-

```
data() {
    return {
      phone: "", // Your initial phone number
      cursorPosition: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onPhoneInput(newValue) {
      const input = this.$refs.phoneRef.$refs.input;

      // Calculate the change in cursor position
      const cursorChange = newValue.length - this.phone.length;

      // Update the phone number
      this.phone = newValue;

      // Calculate the new cursor position
      this.cursorPosition += cursorChange;

      // Ensure the cursor stays within the input field bounds
      this.cursorPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.cursorPosition, this.phone.length));

      // Set the cursor position back to where it should be
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        input.setSelectionRange(this.cursorPosition, this.cursorPosition);
      });
    },
  },
```

But none is working.

Comment: Looks like this is an existing bug and I can see you already log the issue for the same in their GitHub. I have an idea, Can you please try this way - Add the reference to the `vue-tel-input` element and then set the cursor position by doing this `this.$refs.inputPhone.cursorPosition = <current cusrsor position>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I tried a few ways you mentioned but none is working. I updated the question. Can you please have a look at that?